# Hibernate mapping @manytomany

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I got 3 tables: Bus, Driver and BusDriver and I need to get bus entity with set of drivers. I have already understood how to do this but there is a date field in BusDriver and I need to include it in set. For example I got {bus_id, bus_model, ... {driver1, driver2}} but I need {bus_id, bus_model, ... {{driver1, date}, driver2, date}}

Comment: If you display your efforts so far in concrete code and point out the problem, you wil surely get help. As the question stands, I am unsure if anybody can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to map the BusDriver table to an entity to get this attribute.

You should do something like this [exemplo](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would do this by explicitly mapping BusDriver as an entity, then having one or both other entities map BusDriver as ManyToOne or OneToMany (as appropriate).  Your model interface itself can obscure this if necessary by returning a Set or List of Bus (or Driver) instead of the mapping class.